# create Pytorch dataset without downloading

Tags: download, pytorch, dataset

Quite new here, hope this isn't to much of simple question.
I am trying to get into deep learning, starting with *pytorch*.

Thing is, all tutorials I see use downloading in order to build a data set for training and testing.  Unfortunately, I am restricted with my internet connection, meaning I can't download directly from the web.
What I **can** do is download files and transfer them into my computer.

So my question is - in order to use a previously downloaded dataset in *pytorch*:

1. Where should I store it?
2. How do I create a dataset once I have the files on my computer?

If any other information seems important to you I'll be glad to hear, I'm a serious newbie..

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by dataset? Custom? Torchvision? If custom, what kind of files do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which dataset you are asking for. Since you mentioned the "tutorials", I am guessing that you just want to work with a dataset that comes with some library in PyTorch ecosystem (e.g. `torchvision`).

`Dataset` classess in PyTorch ecosystem have a "root" argument in their constrcutors.

```
mnist = MNIST(root='/some/path', download=True)
```

You can simply download it on some machine with internet, and transfer the contents of the folder `/some/path` to your machine at `/my/machine/path`. And simply point to it and turn off the download

```
# on your machine without internet
mnist = MNIST(root='/my/machine/path', download=False)
```

This should work.

Comment: Worked, Thanks.
Couldn't figure out where it was being downloaded to, but this made things much easier.